# How to implements a Font Manager's "install / load a font" in Java

Tags: java, fonts

I am on a Font Manager Java project. Now I want to implement the "install Font" functionality in it. Installing a font, in my understanding, is to copy or move a third party font into the system directory such as Windows/Fonts in Windows.

When I used the normal Java copy routine for this job, however, I received "Access Denied" exception since the destination is a system directory.

The questions are, first, can anyone verify my understanding about "installing a font"? And how do we implement "installing a font" in Java?

Answer (score 0):

This is platform-dependant and requires some privileges, so Java is not the best solution.

Comment: It depends on what else the app is doing/intended for.  If it is just this small part that needs platform dependent stuff and the rest is something java is suited for this could easily be wrapped using jndi for each relevant platform or even bundle a command line tools to invoke to get get the job done.

Comment: @vickirk: is it JNDI or JNI or JNA? Anyway, it sounds like an interesting approach apart from executing a batch file or .reg file or a font installer using Java under Windows environment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant JNI of course, I was in the middle of doing some JNDI lookup code at the time i posted :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use `java.awt.Font.createFont()` methods...I hope it helps...

Please refer to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html

Comment: That is only going to create an instance the op could use in his app, it's not going to register it with the OS.

Comment: @vickirk: Yes, I concur with you if OP really wants to go that level of application. The only choice if this in only Windows-based is to run through a batch file or .reg to install and register a font or maybe run a font installation using a third-party installer. Otherwise, a simple font manager that revolves around its own domain will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it is not just copying the font into the directory (like it seems when doing this in explorer), but also calling some registration functions to register the font.

Comment: The only choice under Java if this in only Windows-based is to run through a batch file or .reg to install and register a font or maybe run a font installation using a third-party installer...it sounds complicated, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Cross posted
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2188576

db